Can any Linux date command print the current time in a time zone other than the current?
I want the just the current time in HH:MM (%R or %H:%M in strftime) in a time zone other the my system's.s
Is this possible with just the date command, and if so, how?

It's the second example from man date (assuming you're using GNU coreutils, which you probably are on a desktop Linux). (I mention that so you have an easier time finding such examples next time!)
TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date +%R


Set the timezone for your date command using the TZ environment variable.
env TZ=Whatever date

